# How to copy file from one server to another server in node js using webDAV protocol?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, module, webdav, file-transfer

I want to copy a file from server to another server in node.js using webdav protocol. or directly upload a file via node.js to MAC server using webdav protocol..

Suggest some modules for node.js that support webdav protocl.. I have tried webdav-sync and replicate-http.. plz share some sample code..

Answer (score 1):

You can try with node module - [poster](https://github.com/rfrench/poster) for directly upload to server

**Stream local file**

```
var poster = require('poster');

var options = {
  uploadUrl: 'http://mysite.com/upload',
  method: 'POST',
  fileId: 'file',
  fields: {
    'myfield': 'value',
    'myfield2': 'value2'
  }
};

poster.post('file.jpg', options, function(err, data) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

**Stream remote file**

```
var poster = require('poster');

var options = {
  uploadUrl: 'http://mysite.com/upload',
  method: 'POST',
  fileId: 'file',
  fields: {
    'myfield': 'value',
    'myfield2': 'value2'
  }
};

poster.post('https://www.google.com/logos/2012/addams11-hp.jpg', options, function(err, data) {
 if (!err) {
console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this work with webdav? How do you use a username/password?